# Source Code for Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0?

Tags: bing-maps

Is the source code available for **Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0 API**?

I have seen the API references on MSDN - [API references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx)

And I have seen the interactive SDK - [interactive SDK](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7)

But I would like to see the javascript source code for the AJAX control. The files that are downloaded by the control are all minified so it's not really possible to understand them.

I'd like to read the source to understand how driving, walking and transit routes are requested from the service, how they are represented as objects, and then how the routes are rendered. This is so that I can build my own custom route type.

Is the source code available somewhere? If so where can it be found?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no unminified version of the Bing Maps AJAX library.

Since it's only Javascript, you can, of course, use Firebug or similar to examine the methods exposed by http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0, and the structure of the calls made to various Bing Maps services, but you'll have to unpick the source code yourself.

Comment: Thanks Alastair, but I have already tried reading the code in IE F12 Developer tools. I can format the code but then the code has been compiled as well as just having whitespace removed, so the names of many internal objects, methods and parameters are fairly meaningless as they have been changed to just single letters most of the time. Maybe I will give it a go anyway but I think it will be pretty difficult. Do you have any other ideas? Otherwise I guesss this is my only option.